# Filtering event always returns topics

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat, events

I have an event in my contract:

`event CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG(uint256 indexed tokenId, address nftOwner, uint256[] randomWords);`

In my JS script, I am trying to run some code only if the event that matches this tokenId has been emitted. This is how I am filtering for this event (hardhat, ethers, contract is called RandomSvg):

```
// Get contract object so we can get address
  let randomSVGObject = await get("RandomSVG");
  let randomSvgAddress = randomSVGObject.address;

  // Get the RandomSVG contract factory
  const randomSvgFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("RandomSVG");
  const randomSvgInterface = randomSvgFactory.interface;

  // Get signer
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  const signer = accounts[0];

  // Create a new randomSVG Contract instance
  const randomSvg = new ethers.Contract(
    randomSvgAddress,
    randomSvgInterface,
    signer
  );

.... call function on RandomSvg that emits the below event....

// Filter for event
const events = randomSvg.filters.CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG(tokenId);
```

Above, `tokenId` is taken from an event in the transaction receipt. The value of this is always 1, and I have checked that there are never any more `tokenId`'s in the contract (eg 2, 3, 4 etc, the code that creates the `tokenId` is only called once).

When I run this and print `events`, I get the following output:

`{"address":"0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9","topics":["0x26cb4155602d63931f31f118192ad576866bf5df054834c85516a4273134bd1e","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"]}`

From my understanding, the first element in `topics` array is the hash of the event signature (https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/events/#events-solidity). The following elements are the indexed parameters, so in this case, it is the `tokenId` which is equal to 1. `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` is equal to 1, so this makes sense.

However, if I run this in my JS script:

`const events = randomSvg.filters.CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG(9999);`

I get this:

`{"address":"0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9","topics":["0x26cb4155602d63931f31f118192ad576866bf5df054834c85516a4273134bd1e","0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000270f"]}`

If we convert the first element of topics (`0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000270f`) to decimal number, we get 9999. This makes no sense to me...

My JS code stated that I wanted to filter `CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG` events where the `tokenId` is equal to 9999. Since there are no `CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG` where `tokenId` is equal to 9999, surely this should return null?

This makes it impossible to determine if an event with a specific indexed value exists, because no matter what `tokenId` you pass in to filter on, you always get a result???

What is the reasoning for this and why is this happening?
How would I determine if an event with a specific value has been emitted?

Additional info:

If I run:

`const events = randomSvg.filters.CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG();`

I get:

`{"address":"0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9","topics":["0x26cb4155602d63931f31f118192ad576866bf5df054834c85516a4273134bd1e"]}`

Which is only the topic hash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```js
// Filter for event
const events = randomSvg.filters.CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG(tokenId);
```

you aren't yet filtering events, but only making the filter (which is the object you've seen).

To filter for actual *live* events from the blockchain:

```js
const filter = randomSvg.filters.CreatedUnfinishedRandomSVG(tokenId);
provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    console.log(log)
    // ...
})
```

Instead to show the events from a receipt:

```js
const tx = ...   // our transaction
const receipt = await tx.wait();
for (let i=0; i<receipt.logs.length; i++) {
        if (receipt.logs[i].address == filter.address) {
            if (receipt.logs[i].topics[0] == filter.topics[0]) {
                console.log(receipt.logs[i])
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't think there's a method to filter these, but nothing you can't do by nesting some `if`s!